Ign to Gz command line questions
I'm in the process of upgrading a package I created to make it easy to simulate Realsense cameras in Gazebo. In my package I support the trigger based RGB camera and had examples of how to trigger an image capture but am running into issues.
My example command to trigger the camera still works in Fortress
ign topic -t "/name/trigger" -m Boolean -p "data: true" -n 1
I assumed the command would change to
gz topic -t "/name/trigger" -m gz.msgs.Boolean -p "data: true" -n 1
But when I run that I get the response Invalid arguments. I also get errors of An instance of Gazebo is not running. when running gz topic -l, when ign topic -l returns a list of valid topics.
The IGN_PARTITION environment variable has bit me before, is there something like this I need to set to make the new commands work properly or do I just need to upgrade to Ionic?
P.S. I'm currently testing this in a ROS2 Iron environment with Gazebo binaries, because that is what my project is using.

The default version of Gazebo that's paired with Iron is Fortress. Are you sure you're running Harmonic (assuming that's the version you're upgrading to?). What steps did you follow for installation?

Yes I am running Fortress with Iron. I just expected that because the gz command line tools and gz.msgs and gz::sim::systems were available when I switched to Iron everything would work but it does not. No worries I will just update my documentation for Harmonic as I upgrade to Jazzy.
